# Anaconda Navigator Not Showing Updates to Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, jupyter

My goal is to install Jupyter Lab 4.0.5 in Anaconda Navigator which was recently released (I believe also a newer version of Jupyter Notebook too) and I want to be able to easily update them (Lab & Notebook) in Anaconda Navigator.

I have seen that updates to Jupyter Notebook and Lab have been released, I updated condo using the following in terminal, but nothing worked:

```
# Updating anaconda navigator
conda deactivate
conda update anaconda-navigator

# updating all packages
conda update --all

# Update Jupyter
conda update jupyter

# Cleaning
conda clean -a
```

I have also looked in the link below, and though this updated Lab, it just showed Lab as being uninstalled in Anaconda Navigator (I was able to run lab in terminal though):

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

I am also using a Mac M2 so installing Anaconda was a bit tedious.

Thank you!

[image]